# CloudKit Account Changes

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am devloping an app using CloudKit and CoreData.  I currently have the app setup so that when the user changes, I use a different locaton for the persistant store.  If the user loggs back in, I can switch back to that persistant store and  pick up right where they left off and not have to redownload data up to that point as well as not loose any changes that might not have been synced when the account changed.

My question is I am now second guessing if this is the right approach (from a data security standpoint) and want to know if there is Apple guidance in this scenario or what other developers might think.  Should I just purge the data when the accont changes (and if there is data loss, not worry about it).

Is there anything I can do about unsynced data when an account changes?

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious use case. I think the answer depends on a few things.

If people are sharing devices and signing in/out of the app, and the app data they are saving is sensitive (PII, financial data, etc.), then I would purge the data and download the new user’s stuff from CloudKit.

If people aren’t sharing devices, and the amount of data you need to pull down is pretty big (several hundred MB or more), then I would keep the local cache in Core Data.

I hope that helps.